# Customer Review Section? in PHP

Tags: php, review

I'm relatively new to PHP. I want to give my users the ability to write reviews of businesses that are located on my website but I'm not sure how to implement the code. In the below URL I want my users to click on the name of the business and be able to write a review of such business. I'm not asking anyone to write the code for me but what I am asking is this, what's the next process? How do I attack/solve this program I'm having. What do I do next ....

Thanks everyone.

http://whatsmyowncarworth.com/practiceTemplate/practice1/33/loans/table3.php

```
<?php
include('init.php');

/*$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id='1' ORDER BY year ASC";*/

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dealers";
if ($result = mysql_query($sql)) {

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Address</th> <th>State</th> <th>City</th> <th>Website</th> ";

    // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $name = $row['name'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $website = $row['website'];
    $maps = $row['maps'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lng = $row['lng'];


        echo("\t<tr>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "<a href='http://$website' target = '_blank'>" . "$name" . "</a></td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$address" . "</td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$state" . "</td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$city" . "</td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "<a href='http://$website' target = '_blank'>" . "$name" . "</a></td>\n");


        /*echo("\t\t<td>" . "<a href='http://$website' target = '_blank'>" . "$name" . "</a></td>\n");

        echo("\t\t<td>" . "<a href='http://$maps' target = '_blank'>" . "$address" . "</td>\n"); 
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "<a href='http://$maps' target = '_blank'>" . "$address" . "</td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$state" . "</td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$city" . "</td>\n");

        echo ("\t\t<td>" . "<a href='http://$website' target = '_blank'>" . "$website" . "</a></td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$maps" . "</td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$lat" . "</td>\n");
        echo("\t\t<td>" . "$lng" . "</td>\n");*/

        // Print out the contents of each row into a table

    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else {
    trigger_error(mysql_error()); // for development only; remove when in production
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you're just starting your project, so I'd look for some tutorials for a more detailed step-by-step guide as to how to proceed, and then come back here if you run into a more specific problem.

Comment: at first you have your php echo a table to the browser before the html open tag... advice to start reading about html page structure (html/head/body tags) and how to combine it with php

Answer (score 2):

I would start by adding an `id` column to your table. Then create a new table for reviews. Columns include `ID (int, PK), businessID (int), review (text or something)`. Then, add a link for more information to each entry that links to `mysite.com/details.php?id=<id>`.

On that page, you show the relevant information for the business again (optional), past reviews (same way you already do it) and a form to get the user's thoughts. When the user submits the form, it will send a `POST` a file (can be the same `details.php` or a different file to avoid clutter) that will read all of the variables in `$_POST[]` and insert it into the database.

On another note, why are you `echo`ing stuff above the `<html>` tag?? All that stuff should go inside the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, It would be better if you put the review button beside the name of the website at the last column. Like this, **John Doe Auto Sales** | **Write a Review**

This way the review button will be close to the name of the website or dealer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes keep reviews like comments. Use unique id column for the business database and in the comment table have a link by using the id. It is better to use the review in the same window or in popup using jQuery dialog or something.